# (Geth) run error: flag provided but not defined: -gasprice

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, testnets, geth-debugging

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/caleteeter/smartcontractdev/blob/master/example1-setup.md) and am able to successfully generate the genesis file and the initialize the bootnode as well but I am unable to start the mining process.
Every time I run :

```
    geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode full --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://df1b4a467476afa30001457da3f489cb045e15a6ed5b1f172abb610fa23607f611edf1a5172c0f0be8d72626de1ed8d8fd68f41586ac410a4a1e2a5322991755@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30310' --networkid 1010 --gasprice '0' --unlock '0x2817bfe894bB0D148a5c43CCb1361f360D474bC1' --password password.txt --mine
```

I get :
`Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -gasprice`
What am I missing ?

PS : The same tutorial was shown [in form of a video](https://youtu.be/EKAbGfxKAQs) and I don't seem to have missed any steps.

Answer (score 1):

it is:

```
--miner.gasprice
```

if you are using geth 1.10.6

```
geth help
```

for more info